# Как так анимировать меню?

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Есть меню, допустим из 5 элементов. Каждому последующему нужно добавлять такой стиль: animation: move 0.3s ease ($num_elem × 0.1s). То есть первому элементу animation: move 0.3s ease 0.1s, второму - animation: move 0.3s ease 0.2s. Нужно, если элементов становится больше, также чтобы у них был номер. Думаю сделать переменные и при посадке в цикле присваивать переменным id элемента меню
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Назначьте элементам меню `id`, в цикле `for` назначайте каждому элементу значение свойства `animation` с помощью конструкции `Element.style` и значения переменной цикла `i`, выбор нужного элемента тоже производится с помощью значения этой переменной, которое подставляется благодаря интерполяции.

Полезная информация для справки:
[Интерполяция](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-interpolation)
[Element.style на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    document.querySelector(`#item-${i}`).style.animation = `move 0.3s ease 0.${i}s`
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="menu-item" id="item-1"></div>
      <div class="menu-item" id="item-2"></div>
      <div class="menu-item" id="item-3"></div>
      <div class="menu-item" id="item-4"></div>
      <div class="menu-item" id="item-5"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не работает ничего

Comment: @Vadizar что не работает? у каждого элемента `.menu-item` назначено свойство `animation` с нужным значением при выполнении кода, посмотрите

Comment: код не исполняется

Comment: @Vadizar код исполняется, там лишь присвоение значений свойства animation, саму анимацию вы не увидите, разумеется